# clockdiff versus ntpdate -q

Tags: ntp, ntpdate

I want to know the time difference between the clocks on two different hosts. I've found `clockdiff` and `ntpdate -q` both perform similar functions. Please provide some insight on the difference between the two in terms of accuracy, what they're actually measuring, etc. If there are other suggestions for providing the same functionality, that would also be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clockdiff` provides 1 ms resolution and it's man page does not mention any attempt to take into account network latency and jitter.

`ntpq` is part of `ntp` and I believe is capable of working with nanosecond resolution. More importantly `ntp` has well-honed and sophisticated algorithms for dealing with latency and jitter.

Few people will need better than millisecond resolution of course.